Why do I get a nested URL of '/auth/auth/ ' if the URL is not existing?
so I was following a tutorial and somehow stuck in a problem wherein if the URL is not existing in the routes.ts. It redirects to a nested /auth/auth/...../login/ instead of redirecting it to localhost:3000/auth/login
middleware.ts
import authConfig from "./auth.config"
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import {
    DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    publicRoutes,
    apiAuthPrefix,
    authRoutes
} from '@/routes'

 const { auth } = NextAuth(authConfig)

export default auth((req) => {
    const { nextUrl } = req;
    const isLoggedIn = !!req.auth;

    const isApiAuthRoute = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(apiAuthPrefix);
    const isPublicRoute = publicRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
    const isAuthRoute = authRoutes.includes(nextUrl.pathname);
    
    if(isApiAuthRoute){
        return ;
    }

    
    if(isAuthRoute){
        if(isLoggedIn){
            return Response.redirect(new URL(DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT, nextUrl))
        }

        return ;
    }


    if(!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute){
        return Response.redirect(new URL('auth/login', nextUrl))
    }

    return ;
  
})
 
export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
}

routes.ts
export const publicRoutes = [
    "/",
    "/auth/new-verification"
    
]

export const authRoutes = [
    "/auth/login",
    "/auth/register",
    "/auth/error"
]


export const apiAuthPrefix = "/api/auth"


export const DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/settings"

For example, I've created a button here that will redirect to another page that is not included yet in my routes.ts.
<Button size="sm" variant="link" asChild className="px-0 font-normal">
  <Link href="/auth/reset">Forgor Password?</Link>
</Button>;


For example I clicked it.
this is the url

http://localhost:3000/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/login


In this function statement, I forgot to include a / before the (auth/login)
    if(!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute){
        return Response.redirect(new URL('auth/login', nextUrl))
    }

I change it into this
if(!isLoggedIn && !isPublicRoute){
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', nextUrl))
}


The issue you’re encountering is likely due to the way NextAuth handles unhandled routes. By default, NextAuth redirects unhandled routes to /auth/login for authentication. In your case, since the route you’re trying to redirect to (/auth/reset) is not defined in your routes.ts file, NextAuth is redirecting you to /auth/login instead.
To fix this issue, you need to add the auth/reset route to your routes.ts file. Here’s what your updated routes.ts file should look like:
export const publicRoutes = [
    "/",
    "/auth/new-verification",
    "/auth/reset",
]

export const authRoutes = [
    "/auth/login",
    "/auth/register",
    "/auth/error"
]

export const apiAuthPrefix = "/api/auth"

export const DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/settings"

After making this change, NextAuth should correctly redirect unauthenticated users to the /auth/login page, while authenticated users will be able to access the /auth/reset page as expected.
